# Admin form factory multiselect / checkbox

Tags: magento2, forms, adminform

I am trying to implement a multi choice for a custom field.

Currently i use form factory with this for simple fields :

```
$fieldset->addField(
            'mail',
            'text',
            ['name' => 'mail', 'label' => __('Mail'), 'title' => __('Mail'), 'required' => true]
        );
```

Now i want checkbox or multiselect, i already see this :

```
$fieldset->addField(
            'test',
            'multiselect',
            [
                'name' => 'name',
                'label' => __('test'),
                'title' => __('test'),
                'required' => true,
                'values' => $optionLanguage,
                'disabled' => false
            ]
        );
```

But I don't know how to write my `$optionLanguage` array, I just want simple option (option 1: Fr, option 2: En).

Don't matter **checkbox** or **multiselect**, **checkbox** is better for me but if **multiselect** is easier i will go for it.

Answer (score 1):

Found solution for multiselect :

```
'values' => array(
            '1'=> array( 'label' => 'Français', 'value' => 'fr'),
            '2'=> array( 'label' => 'English', 'value' => 'en'),
            '3'=> array( 'label' => 'Espanol', 'value' => 'es'),
            '4'=> array( 'label' => 'Italiano', 'value' => 'it'),
            '5'=> array( 'label' => 'Deutsch', 'value' => 'de'),
            '6'=> array( 'label' => 'Român', 'value' => 'ro'),
          ),
```